# Solution of linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I am worried about use of **differential operator method** to solve linear ODE.  In this method, we unknowingly treat L(D), *Polynomial operator*,  as a real polynomial in variable x. And, we factorize it in linear factors, (D - α).

Can someone explain it why
$$ L_1(D) L_2(D) L_3(D) = L_1L_2L_3(D)?$$

Comment: The details require a bit of extra linear algebra beyond a standard first course. Short answer - composition.

Comment: The ring generated by one element is always commutative, there is no difference, structurally, between $\Bbb C[x]$ and $\Bbb C[D]$.